# Ubuntu 16.04 - Computer has no battery but indicates a false battery is present and ac adaptor is offline

Tags: 16.04, drivers, power-management, battery

The computer is NOT a laptop - it is a mini-desktop - there is no internal battery and it runs directly off an ac adapter.  Yet, Ubuntu reports a false battery present and that the ac adapter is offline.  There is no way to set the ac adapter online in the system software but it is the only power source which operates the computer.  The system runs fine on the ac adapter.

The bios has no settings for power supply other than auto-restart if the ac power is lost (American Megatrends) which I have set to on.  The system should remain online while the ac power is on but it does an auto shut down when it detects the (non existent) battery is low.

upower -d

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_axp288_charger
  native-path:          axp288_charger
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Saturday, January 04, 2020 AM08:41:24 EST (18726 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_axp288_fuel_gauge
  native-path:          axp288_fuel_gauge
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Saturday, January 04, 2020 PM01:53:28 EST (2 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       low
    energy:              1.34969 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         19.2812 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.2768 W
    voltage:             4.488 V
    time to empty:       1.1 hours
    percentage:          7%
    capacity:            100%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1578164008  1.277   discharging
    1578164007  1.210   discharging
    1578163916  1.142   discharging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Saturday, January 04, 2020 PM01:53:28 EST (2 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       low
    energy:              1.34969 Wh
    energy-full:         19.2812 Wh
    energy-rate:         1.2768 W
    time to empty:       1.1 hours
    percentage:          7%
    icon-name:          'battery-caution-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.4
  on-battery:      yes
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  no
  critical-action: HybridSleep

This is intended as a 24-7 system to remain online unattended but I have to monitor it because of the faulty power software settings.  Is there a fix or some setting/file I am missing to disable the battery and recognize the ac adaptor?

Comment: Maybe a Problem with  upower. Please show `upower -d` edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already found the solution but I'm replying here because I had the same exact problem on my new computer, an ACEPC T11, and I could only find your post at first.
After hours of investigation, I eventually found the solution [here](https://anto.pt/post/acepcfix/).

Basically, you need to change the configuration of UPower to prevent it from polling the battery status and wait for the battery itself to send updates.
Since there's no battery, its charge value will remain constant and the system won't shut down.

Update `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` and set

```
NoPollBatteries=true
```

I understand that this is not a "real" solution but it gets the job done, at least for me (no more power issues)